# Cursor remains at the end when I try to give user input in getline

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

The following is the the code for asking a name and then returning a statement which has your name in it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "What is your name:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cout << "Your name is " << name << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program and type the name, sometimes you type the input in wrong manner and hence you use the arrow keys to go left or right. However, when I use the left arrow key, instead of the cursor going to the left, `^[[D` is printed. And when I use the right arrow key, `^[[C` is printed.

My question is how can I avoid this and actually move the cursor to the right or left. I use Vim text editor on Linux.

Comment: What's your environment?

Comment: If you mean IDE, I don't use one. I just use vim in Linux and use g++ to compile the program. And I run the program in the terminal.

Comment: I was asking about your environment because your program would let your terminal handle processing the left/right arrows.  If you're getting symbols like that, there's something wrong with your terminal.

Comment: What you ask to do is only possible by writing a mini-editor. What might help instead is using the backspace key and overwrite the wrong part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to handle this sort of thing is the use the editline or GNU readline linrary (which is a C libary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <editline/readline.h>
#include <editline/history.h>

int main() {
    const char *name = readline("What is your name:");
    printf("Your name is %s.\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

You need the libray installed, and you link your program with -leditline,

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also wanted to know if there was a way of doing this with `std::string`? Since currently I would have to convert char array to string. And I wanted to use strings.